# Mocking in Typescript unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocking

The problem is that mocking in Typescript can get tricky if the object is complex enough (well in any strongly-typed language). You would usually mock some extra stuff just to make code compile and in C# for instance, you can use AutoFixture or similar. On the other hand Javascript is dynamic language and it's possible to mock only part of the object that's needed for test to run.

So in Typescript unit test I can declare my dependency using `any` type and thus  easily mock it. Do you see any drawbacks of such approach?

```
let userServiceMock: MyApp.Services.UserService = {
    // lots of thing to mock
}
```

vs

```
let userServiceMock: any = {
    user: {
         setting: {
             showAvatar: true
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My experience with unit tests in TypeScript definitely shows that it's worth to keep all mock objects typed. When you leave your mocks with a type of `any`, it becomes problematic during a rename. The IDE won't correctly discover which occurrences of the `user` or `settings` param should be changed. Of course, writing mock objects manually with a complete interface is really laborious.

Fortunately, there are two tools for TypeScript that allows creating type-safe mock objects: [ts-mockito](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito) (inspired by [Java mockito](http://mockito.org/)) and [typemoq](https://github.com/florinn/typemoq) (inspired by [C# Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)).

Comment: I wrote an article comparing the two libraries: https://medium.com/@michal.m.stocki/when-it-comes-to-mocking-in-typescript-be8531d39327

Comment: I've written my own tool that handles this same problem, and I'd love some feedback on it: https://medium.com/default-to-open/unit-testing-with-angular-and-ineeda-76746a0c8f58

Comment: I developed a really awesome fully strong-typed library for this using TypeScript 3.0 and ES6 proxies: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluffy-spoon/substitute

Answer (score 9):

Now that TypeScript 3 is out, full strong typing can finally be expressed! I took advantage of this and ported NSubstitute to TypeScript.

It can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluffy-spoon/substitute

I made a comparison versus most popular frameworks here: https://medium.com/@mathiaslykkegaardlorenzen/with-typescript-3-and-substitute-js-you-are-already-missing-out-when-mocking-or-faking-a3b3240c4607

Notice how it can create fakes from interfaces, and have full strong typing along the way!

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by @Terite `any` type on mocks is poor choice as there would be no relationship between mock and its actual type / implementation. So improved solution may be casting partially-mocked object to mocks type:

```
export interface UserService {
    getUser: (id: number) => User;
    saveUser: (user: User) => void;
    // ... number of other methods / fields
}
```

.......

```
let userServiceMock: UserService = <UserService> {
    saveUser(user: User) { console.log("save user"); }
}
spyOn(userServiceMock, 'getUser').andReturn(new User());
expect(userServiceMock.getUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedUserId);
```

It also worth mention that Typescript won't allow to cast any object that has extra members (superset or derived type). Means that your partial mock is actually of base type to the `UserService` and can be safely cast. e.g.

```
// Error: Neither type '...' nor 'UserService' is assignable to the other.
let userServiceMock: UserService = <UserService> {
     saveUser(user: User) { console.log("save user"); },
     extraFunc: () => { } // not available in UserService
}
```

Comment: Why, is it so important for you to have partially mocked objects? It's rather bad idea to have public fields and public methods in the same service. It could be better to define method `setAvatarVisibility(visible:boolean)` and keep the `user` field private. Then you'll avoid manual spying. Note that in `spyOn(userServiceMock, 'saveUser');` the string name of a method won't be refactored automatically by the IDE.

Comment: Yet another, better solution would be to keep the `user` object outside the service at all. The code is easier to test if we keep services stateless. What do you think about making the `UserService` receiving the user to it's method: `saveUser(user:User):void;`?

Comment: I used this code as example only, maybe not the best one, but it is not something I was trying to mock. I am just looking for a general solution. And yes your examples are better of course, thanks for advice.

Comment: This answer is no longer true in TypeScript 3. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As for functional objects you can use mock libraries that support typescript, or javascript libraries that have type definitions. In both cases types exist only in design time.
So jasminesjs has Spy functionality and you can use it in type safety way like this:

```js
spyOn(SomeTypescriptClass, "SomeTypescriptClassProperty");
```

The IDE and typescript compiler will handle it properly. The only drawback is that parameters are not supported. If you need type support for parameter you need to use typescript mock libraries. I can add another mock library for typescript [moq.ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moq.ts)

As for DTO objects you can use this approach:

```js
export type IDataMock<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: IDataMock<T[P]>;
};

export function dataMock<T>(instance: IDataMock<T>): T {
  return instance as any;
}

// so where you need
const obj = dataMock<SomeBigType>({onlyOneProperty: "some value"});
```

As I remember IDataMock can be replaced with standard Partial interface from typescript.